# Fast Data load from RDBMS to Ignite Cache

Tags: java, ignite

I have a user interface which internally connects to a RDBMS. From the UI, a user can select any number of tables or the user can write a select query to get a result set and load it into an Apache Ignite cache. Can you please suggest with sample examples or API which loads the data into cache in table format.

Answer (score 0):

You need to use the [Data Streamer API](https://ignite.apache.org/docs/latest/data-streaming). As for how long it will take: it depends on the size of your cluster, the performance of your network, the size of the records, etc. Ignite scales horizontally, so it'll be able to load it as fast as you can send it with a big enough cluster.

Comment: Thanks Stephan, am using Datastreamer API but it expected POJO/Entity class ref to load the data ,in my case tables are dynamic and at run time pojo classes creation in not possible, can you please advise how to load dynamic tables data into cache in table format( also i observed that using BinaryObjectBuilder API can load the data but its in a JSON format-Key-Value pairs but i need to store it in a table format).  Sample code ref. CacheConfiguration<Long, Employee> cacheCfg = new CacheConfiguration<>(cacheName);cacheCfg.setIndexedTypes(AffinityKey.class, Employee.class);

Comment: Ignite is not a document database. The expectation is that all your rows are basically the same. How would SQL work if a column is only present in some records?